# Understanding the flawed audit review system

Tags: discussion, answers, reference-question

I came across [a post](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/15107/audit-failed-why-is-this-not-opinion-based), analyzed its content, and subsequently answered, drawing from [my own experience](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/12185/one-of-those-trick-questions) of encountering a similar issue in the past.

In an effort to provide a comprehensive answer rooted in addressing the underlying cause, I searched SU meta's search, attempting to locate an established canonical response that succinctly addresses such inquiries in which I was unsuccessful.

#### The essence of the matter

The existing review queue audit is **flawed and requires updating**; fortunately, encountering failures is **generally manageable**, and **proactive strategies exist to identify and address flaws effectively**.

---

**I'm seeking a thorough and canonical response** that covers these aspects as well as any additional considerations contributors may suggest. This response will serve as a reference for all related inquiries, streamlining discussions about questions like "*I answered review questions honestly and failed audit; should X really be Y?*" so that we can avoid revisiting the same issues repeatedly.

### Related Posts

**Note:** *I've posted relevant questions, as have numerous others, and even "current" moderators have historically raised similar issues here. Below are some examples with links for reference.*

- [Bad audit question - failed audit on question that should have been closed](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/9223/bad-audit-question-failed-audit-on-question-that-should-have-been-closed)
- [Why is offensive content added to review "trick" questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301616/why-is-offensive-content-added-to-review-trick-questions)
- [Review Audit Test failed - Why](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/14621/review-audit-test-failed-why)
- [Disagreeing with a failed review audit](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/8377/disagreeing-with-a-failed-review-audit)
- [Audit failed, why is this not opinion based?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/15107/audit-failed-why-is-this-not-opinion-based)
- [Review Test error](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/6800/review-test-error)
- [Is this a review bug to the dreaded test questions](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/12478/is-this-a-review-bug-to-the-dreaded-test-questions)
- [Design flaw in the review audit system](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/9248/design-flaw-in-the-review-audit-system)
- [Can the review system be fixed?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/11636/can-the-review-system-be-fixed)
- [Review audit - dissagreement](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/13656/review-audit-dissagreement)

Comment: Every community shares the same system, as a community we are at the whim, of the Stack Exchange developers. For that reason this question probably should be migrated to Meta Stack Exchange.

Comment: @Ramhound Although this appears to be a widespread problem impacting all Stack Exchange communities, I have observed it frequently on the Super User Meta. Consequently, I believe it would be fitting to have a comprehensive answer with all the necessary caveats documented on the Super User Meta. While we may not have control over the adjustments made by Stack Exchange developers, we can take the initiative to ensure that our community has a thorough post on the Super User Meta.

Comment: SU is perhaps more vulnerable to this, because the best answer is not always as clear as for example in SE. Personally, I've given up on reviewing a long time ago, because I didn't always agree with the "right" answer and was penalized as a result. It became too tiresome to check if a post was real or a test.

Answer (score 1):

### Harmful Content in Trick Audit Reviews: A Call to Action

Concerning the presence of ***any offensive content introduced by the audit system's algorithm*** in the trick audit review questions,
if you encounter **content containing profanity, [racism, hate speech, discriminatory language](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301616/why-is-offensive-content-added-to-review-trick-questions), illegal activities, violence, explicit material, or any other forms of harmful content**, please take appropriate action by disclosing it promptly.

Increased reporting, disclosure, and visibility increase the likelihood of those with the capability to implement impactful technical solutions taking notice.

Here are some reporting **tips to maximize visibility and raise awareness:**

- Capture screenshots as evidence of the harmful content.
- Note the relevant URL in the specific section where the system-generated harmful content appears.
- Share your concerns by posting a question on the https://meta.stackexchange.com/ community.
- Include supporting evidence for your content when making a post.
- Remain resilient in the face of responses like:

  - "*I've seen much worse*"
  - "*Not sure it's worth fixing*"
  - "*It's not a major issue*"
  - "*Why ask this*"
  - "*Voting to close*"
- Remain resilient in the face of lack of responses.
- It's advisable to report every occurrence of observed harmful content as soon as it is noticed.

#### What about reposting harmful content

If you're hesitant about reposting a screenshot containing harmful content directly in the post, I recommend adding `>!`  before `[![Enter image description here][1]][1]` in screen shots. This turns it into a screen shot that requires a click to reveal the content rather than displaying it by default. However, it's crucial to include the evidence in the post for awareness purposes.

Here's an example [post using the strategy I used when I initially observed this issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301616/why-is-offensive-content-added-to-review-trick-questions). It illustrates how the approach functions, the nature of comments it elicits, and the absence of a direct answer in the format of an actual answer.

[image]

Comment: If I must take on the role of the sole contributor, I will systematically analyze each element, delivering a thorough response to specific areas on a weekly or monthly basis until I've covered them all to my satisfaction. Given today's focus on offensive and harmful language/content generated by the system, I've addressed practical strategies at this level.