Failed audit test: "how to run the program in safe mode windows 10?"
I just saw the question with the mentioned title, the question was "How to run the program in Windows 10 safe mode? I'd like to be able to run every program in safe mode,for example spotplayer How can I do this in Windows 10?".
So I thought by myself "That guy has heard somewhere about "Safe Mode" and he wants to use it but he does not even know that "Safe Mode" applies on the whole computer, but that's not a problem, as one of the first comments explains this to him.", so that looks ok!
=> Reaction from the site: "NO!!! NOT OK!!! YOU HAVE FLUNKED AN AUDIT TEST!!!"
Really, guys?!?

What's the question here? If it's "Really, guys?!?", then... yeah, audits aren't great (they're there to make sure you're not clicking mindlessly; failing one or two now and again is not a big deal)

Hang on, this is your third question on audits... have you considered the "don't worry about failing an audit or two" (or three) approach?

@bertieb: it's difficult not to worry about a mistake if you get thrown out the door for making a mistake :-)

I'm not sure what "thrown out the door" refers to. If you mean getting review banned, you don't get banned for failing a single review (or even two), hence the advice. If you refer to the harsh tone the audit throws at you, the point is to jolt people who might not have been paying attention. Yes it's not ideal to get that jolt when the audit is predicated on something suboptimal, but in the grand scheme of things? Don't worry about it

I've failed audits, more than once myself. Its fine. If you think you got review banned unfairly, its probably going to be fine to 1) post the audits you failed 2) make at least a minimal case for why you weren't sleepwalking through it. Since its meant to stop robo reviewing, I'd personally, as a mod, consider removing a 'unfair' review ban quite seriously.

It’s helpful if you link to the audit when you want to complain about an audit candidate. If it’s a bad audit candidate then the community downvoting the question (if it’s a bad question) can prevent it from being an audit candidate. I will say what I said a dozen times before, open the question in another tab, if you find it difficult to recognize when a review item is actually an audit. I remember the question, it was a bad question, and was deleted There was both “ok” about that question

Check this out: https://meta.superuser.com/questions/15115/understanding-the-flawed-audit-review-system

Allow me to plagiarise myself (1):

Don't worry about failing an audit or two

The system is far from perfect. You're not the first to encounter this, and you won't be the last. In fact, this is the third time you've asked about audits here on meta. I sense a pattern.
Audits tend to be drawn from one of two sources:

QAs that have gone HNQ or are otherwise highly rated (system: "obviously good")
QAs that have been downvoted and/or deleted (system: "obviously bad")

Those of you with a discerning mind will quickly point out that not all that glitters is gold, and that not all HNQs are great QAs. Contrariwise, not all deleted questions are rightfully so.
But here's the thing: it doesn't really matter in the grand scheme of things. Don't worry about failing an audit or two. Would it be better if the audits were better? Sure! Is SE gonna change 'em? Naw†, they're bedded in. Working as designed. Too much inertia.
So you failed an audit- I'd suggest that you don't worry about failing an audit or two.

†: You might convince them to adopt some kind of GenAI audit, but that's very much a "be careful what you wish for (look what your careless hands have wrought)" scenario. I'd rather get shouted at for stupidly clicking "Edit" and failing an audit on an "obviously good" question that could use some typos fixed and links than encourage that sort of nonsense. So yeah, just... don't worry about failing an audit or two.
